# Cache refresh is showing error with @cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

Can someone help me to debug this error ?

> 2015-03-11 14:59:03,844 [cachename.data] ERROR
>   n.s.e.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory - Disk Write of -351643849550012
>   failed:  java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   com.googlecode.ehcache.annotations.RefreshableCacheEntry  at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:422)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.Element.writeObject(Element.java:867)
>   ~[ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:940)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
>   ~[na:1.6.0_45]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.util.MemoryEfficientByteArrayOutputStream.serialize(MemoryEfficientByteArrayOutputStream.java:97)
>   ~[ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.serializeElement(DiskStorageFactory.java:399)
>   ~[ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory.write(DiskStorageFactory.java:381)
>   ~[ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$DiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:473)
>   ~[ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]    at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$PersistentDiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:1067)
>   [ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]     at
>   net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStorageFactory$PersistentDiskWriteTask.call(DiskStorageFactory.java:1051)
>   [ehcache-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>   [na:1.6.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_45]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
>   [na:1.6.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
>   [na:1.6.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>   [na:1.6.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>   [na:1.6.0_45]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_45]

I am using cache refresh with @cacheable annotation:

CacheFetchDao.java

```
@Cacheable(cacheName = "cachename",refreshInterval=10000, decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.REFRESHING_SELF_POPULATING_CACHE)
//@Cacheable( value = "cachename", key = "#key")
public List<Account> getAccounts(String key) {
    //call to database
    return res;
}
```

CachefetchEndpoint.java

```
    @GET
@Path("/Accounts")
@WebMethod(operationName = "Accounts")
public List<Account> Accounts() {
    return dao.getAccounts("accounts");
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
    updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" 
    dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>  

    <defaultCache    
        maxElementsInMemory="100"  
        eternal="false"    
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"    
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"    
        overflowToDisk="true"    
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"    
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"    
        diskPersistent="false"    
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"    
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>  

    <!-- The cache configuration for our Currency cache -->  
    <cache name="cachename"  
        maxElementsInMemory="3000"  
        eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"  
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"  
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
    </cache>  
</ehcache>
```

and config.xml

```
 <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehcache" />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
        </bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >
            <property name="configLocation" value="ehcache.xml" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope your Account Type implements Serializable interface
? Can you post that as well?

Comment: public final class Account implements Serializable{ ...attributes+ getter +setter
}

Comment: Does your account object compose other types which might not be implementing Serializable? 
From exception it is pretty much clear that someone didn't implemented Serializable hence java io is failing to persist that object to Disk.

Comment: Account class only has String and Double in it.

Comment: Call to database query is 
List<Account> res = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(source).query(
    select.toString(), empty, new AccountRowMapper2());

Comment: which version of ehcache you are using? everything else look good in above code but are you sure this is the only place from where this exception is getting originated? see if you have anything else which is using ehchache. provide more log details if possible.

Comment: I can provide you logs after few hours (away from system now), but it seems this is the issue http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/issues/detail?id=93 what I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by removing diskPersistent="false". diskPersistent="false" can't be used with  decoratedCacheType= DecoratedCacheType.REFRESHING_SELF_POPULATING_CACHE